# Why does the BeautifulSoup in Python fail?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am getting this error when importing BeautifulSoup:

```bash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I've successfully installed BeautifulSoup according to the post install method.

And here is the process all the way to the error:

```bash
. ./.venv/bin/activate
(.venv) nscraper % which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3

(.venv) nscraper % python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('purelib'))"
/Users/eric/Documents/gitea/nscraper/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages

(.venv) nscraper % pip install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.12.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>1.2 (from beautifulsoup4)
  Using cached soupsieve-2.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.12.3-py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Using cached soupsieve-2.5-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Installing collected packages: soupsieve, beautifulsoup4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.12.3 soupsieve-2.5

(.venv) nscraper % python index.py 399091
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/Documents/gitea/nscraper/index.py", line 1, in <module>
    from MyHTMLParser import MyHTMLParser
  File "/Users/eric/Documents/gitea/nscraper/MyHTMLParser.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

The output of `pip list` is

```
Package        Version
-------------- -------
beautifulsoup4 4.12.3
pip            24.0
soupsieve      2.5
```

Anybody know what's going on here? Thx

Comment: what is the output of  `pip list` ?

Comment: try runnig it with `python3 index.py 399091`

Comment: I am thoroughly confused. That worked! Thanks. I wonder why that is. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: check `which python` and `which python3`, something is wrong with your venv